# How to run Kafka Connect connectors automatically (e.g. in production)?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

Is there a way to automatically load (multiple) Kafka Connect connectors upon the start of Kafka Connect (e.g. in Confluent Platform)?

What I've found out so far:

Confluent Docs state to use the `bin/connect-standalone`
the command for Standalone Mode with a properties file for the worker and for every single connector.

For Distributed Mode you have to run the connector via REST API.

https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html#standalone-mode, https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/managing/configuring.html#standalone-example

Is there another method, e.g. to include all connectors that should be run in the 'connect-[standalone|distributed].properties' file (similar to providing KSQL queries file in ksql-server.properties) so that they are loaded automatically upon the start of Kafka Connect (e.g. in Confluent Platform)?

Or are the connectors loaded "manually" as described above even in production environments?

Answer (score 4):

Normally, you'd have to use the REST API when running Kafka Connect in distributed mode. However, you can use docker compose to script the creation of connectors; 
@Robin Moffatt has written a nice [article](https://rmoff.net/2018/12/15/docker-tips-and-tricks-with-ksql-and-kafka/) about this:

```
kafka-connect:
  image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.1.2
  environment:
    CONNECT_REST_PORT: 18083
    CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: "kafka-connect"
    […]
  volumes:
    - $PWD/scripts:/scripts
  command: 
    - bash 
    - -c 
    - |
      /etc/confluent/docker/run & 
      echo "Waiting for Kafka Connect to start listening on kafka-connect ⏳"
      while [ $$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w %{http_code} http://kafka-connect:8083/connectors) -eq 000 ] ; do 
        echo -e $$(date) " Kafka Connect listener HTTP state: " $$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w %{http_code} http://kafka-connect:8083/connectors) " (waiting for 200)"
        sleep 5 
      done
      nc -vz kafka-connect 8083
      echo -e "\n--\n+> Creating Kafka Connect Elasticsearch sink"
      /scripts/create-es-sink.sh 
      sleep infinity
```

> Notes:
>
> - In the command section, `$` are replaced with `$$` to avoid the error
>     Invalid interpolation format for "command" option
> - `sleep infinity` is
>     necessary, because we’ve sent the `/etc/confluent/docker/run` process to
>     a background thread (`&`) and so the container will exit if the main
>     `command` finishes.
> - The actual script to configure the connector is a
>     `curl` call in a separate file. You could build this into the Docker
>     Compose but it feels a bit yucky.
> - You could combine both this and the
>     technique above if you wanted to install a custom connector plugin
>     before launching Kafka Connect, e.g.
>     `confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-gcs:5.0.0 /etc/confluent/docker/run`